# Ruby on Rails Accessing params from controller from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to access parameters in my controller as strings

When I log

```
Rails.logger.debug  "!!!" << "#{params[:username]}"
```

nothing comes after the exclamation points even though

```
Rails.logger.debug params.inspect
```

shows that username has a value.

Can someone please tell me how to get the username value to show up in my log debugging statement?

Controller Code:

```
def create
    Rails.logger.debug params.inspect
    Rails.logger.debug  "!!!" << "#{@user[:username]}"

    @user = Users.new(user_params)

    {params[:birth_year]}"
    if @user.save
        redirect_to(:controller => 'users', :action => 'index')
    else
        render(:controller => 'access', :action => 'index')
    end
end
```

last few lines of logged info:

```
"user"=>{"username"=>"TrevorTT" ...

!!!
```

Comment: show the controller code you have.

Comment: Show the full controller code... and hope you have the white-listing method..

Comment: show the output of `params.inspect`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user would not work in this line `Rails.logger.debug  "!!!" << "#{@user[:username]}"` because it's not created yet. Either move 
`@user = Users.new(user_params)` above logger.

But as per my understanding you just want to log `username` params only.

So you can do it like this `params[:user][:username]` because `username` nested under `user` params. So your code should be:

```
def create
    Rails.logger.debug params.inspect
    Rails.logger.debug  "!!!" << "#{params[:user][:username]}"

    ....
end
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, I was actually using params[:username] but I didn't realize that I needed to use the 2d array

Answer (score 0):

`@user` is called before it is defined. It will return nil.

```
def create
  #...
  Rails.logger.debug  "!!!" << "#{@user[:username]}"   # <-- @user is nil

  @user = User.new(user_params)
```

You can either leave the line in place and use `user_params`

```
def create
  #...
  Rails.logger.debug  "!!!" << "#{user_params[:username]}" 

  @user = User.new(user_params)
```

or move the line below `@user =`

```
def create
  #...      
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  Rails.logger.debug  "!!!" << "#{@user[:username]}"
```

Also, your model names should be singluar (eg. `User`).